# Disable push notification for particular VC

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am working on chat screen and reciving push notification for chat messages, but I want to disable push when the chat screen for that particular user is open, I have goen through some to the questions but that didn't help

previous code

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

I have tried it to change like this

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo        
    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    
    if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        
        if let vc = (topController as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.last as? MessagesViewController {
            if vc.conversation.id == (userInfo["gcm.notification.channelID"] as? String) {
                completionHandler([])
                return
            }
            else {
                completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
            }
        }
        else {
            completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
        }
    }
    else {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

}
```

when ever the notification code it executes the **completionHandler([])** line of code but itdidn't stop push from being visible

Comment: Are you 100% sure it calls the `completionHandler([])`? Do you have a breakpoint there, maybe add some logging to be sure!?

Comment: yes I'm sure, code is executing that line, thats the reason I'm confused what I'm doing wrong hear

Answer (score 0):

this is answer for those who are stuck at the same situation, I'm not sure what is happening but this worked for me

instead of empty array **completionHandler([])**
just don't write this line and it is good to go